# Big O notation changing the power

Tags: big-o, computer-science

I want to Express each of the following functions using Big-O notation.

a(n) = 2n + 3n^2 + nlog(n)

b(n) = 5nlog(n) + 10n^3 + n^2

for a(n) I assumed that the answer would be O(n^2) However apparently it is O(n^3)
this is the same for b(n) where I assumed the notation would be O(n^3) however it is O(n^4). Is it a rule to round up the power when writing the notation? Why would this be the case? Isn't the notation supposed to take the upper-bound?

Comment: `a(n)` is indeed `O(n^2)`, and `b(n)` is `O(n^3)`. Why do you think it is otherwise ?

Comment: from posts online. Their logic for a(n) was "nlog(n) is equal to O(n) but we have a n^2 terms which us equal to O(n^3) therefore O(n^3)". is this just wrong?

Comment: I think it is as I wrote above.

Comment: If those other posts are confusing you, you should tell us what they say, as well as refer to them so that we might understand what caused the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, *a(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)* and *b(n) = O(n<sup>3</sup>)*.

However, notice that *a(n)* is also *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* and indeed *O(n<sup>1000</sup>)*. Usually though, we want to express the tightest bound we can find.